# Can't access value of dropdown modified by Ajax

Tags: 7, forms, ajax

I have two dropdown fields, #2 is modified by Ajax based on #1 selection. When I try to access #2 value in the submit handler, I get an empty result. I've checked this against the docs and examples and I can't see what am I doing wrong here?

The code:

```
function admin_select_meeting_type_form($form, &$form_state) {
  $meet_types = get_meeting_types();
  $form['meet_types']=array(
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#title' => t('Select meeting type:'),  
        '#options' => $meet_types,      
    '#required' => TRUE,
    '#ajax' => array(
      'callback' => 'ajax_select_meeting_type_callback',
      'wrapper' => 'meetlist-div',
      'effect' => 'slide',
    ),  
  );    
  $form['meet'] = array(
    '#type' => 'container',
    '#prefix' => '<div id="meetlist-div">',
    '#suffix' => '</div>',                      
  );
  $form['submit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',                
    '#value' => t('Save')
  );              
  return $form;
}


function admin_select_meeting_type_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
    drupal_set_message('You selected:' . $form_state['values']['meet']); 
}

// Implement ajax update of meeting select field
function ajax_select_meeting_type_callback($form, $form_state) {
     if ($form['meet_types']['#value']) {
        $dispmeet = array(); // truncated for brevity, my array processing is done here
        $form['meet'] = array(
           '#type' => 'select',
           '#prefix' => '<div id="meetlist-div">',
           '#suffix' => '</div>',
           '#title' => t('Select meeting:'),
           '#values' => array_keys($dispmeet),
           '#options' => $dispmeet,     
           '#required' => TRUE,
        );              
        return $form['meet'];
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't build the form element in your callback.  You want something like this:

```
function admin_select_meeting_type_form($form, &$form_state) {
  $meet_types = drupal_map_assoc(array('conference' => 'conference', 'event' => 'event'));
  $form['meet_types']=array(
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#title' => t('Select meeting type:'),  
    '#options' => $meet_types,      
    '#required' => TRUE,
    '#ajax' => array(
      'callback' => 'ajax_select_meeting_type_callback',
      'wrapper' => 'meetlist-div',
      'effect' => 'slide',
      'method' => 'replace'
    ),  
  );    
  $form['meet_container'] = array(
    '#prefix' => '<div id="meetlist-div">',
    '#suffix' => '</div>',                      
  );
  if (!empty($form_state['values']['meet_types'])) {
    $form['meet_container']['meet'] = array(
      '#type' => 'select',
      '#title' => t('Select meeting:'),
      '#options' => drupal_map_assoc(array('test', 'test2')),     
      '#required' => TRUE,
    );    
  }
  $form['submit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',                
    '#value' => t('Save')
  );              

  return $form;
}

function admin_select_meeting_type_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
    print_r($form_state['values']);
    die();
}

// Implement ajax update of meeting select field
function ajax_select_meeting_type_callback($form, &$form_state) {
  if ($form['meet_types']['#value']) {
    return $form['meet_container'];
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Chris! Works great, I just added a minor note on where I added the processing for ['meet'] #options once the first pulldown was selected.